# Control-M using Automation-API {RESTapi} with PostMan

Tags: control-m

I am using Control-M Automation API, I am able to authenticate myself using

```
POST Session/Login
```

I am using response token as  `Authorization = Bearer + token`, however from here on i am unable to run any other API such as samples or run
When I use `GET {{ctmUrl}} /samples` I am getting below error

```
   {
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "Server Error",
          "code": "500",
          "uri": "/samples"
        }
      ]
    }
```

When i use `GET {{ctmURL}}/run`, then i am getting below error

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unsupported Media Type",
      "code": "415",
      "uri": "/run"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Can you get me the ctrlm url which you used? Can you paste the url here please?

Answer (score 0):

Set a header key/value pair of "Content-Type" and "application/json"

Status 415 is saying your request is not the correct data type. Even if your input is valid, you need to specify a content type.